# Is the C*-algebra of compact operators nuclear?

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Is the algebra of compact operators a nuclear C*-algebra in the sense that there exists a unique C*-norm on the algebraic tensor product $A\odot\mathcal K$ for all C*-algebras $A$? If so, where can I find a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the $C^*$-algebra of compact operators is nuclear.  There is a proof in chapter 6 of Murphy's *$C^*$-algebras and Operator Theory*.  The idea of the proof is that $M_n(\mathbb C)$ is nuclear for all $n$, $\mathcal K$ is the direct limit of the $M_n(\mathbb C)$ under upper left corner inclusions, and nuclearity is preserved under direct limits.

Comment: You can do it directly too, I think. Compressing by finite-rank projections into matrix-algebras (the c.p maps from the compacts) should work?